# Importing a module that imports another module using importlib

Tags: python

I've looked at a number of other solutions but they don't appear to directly address my problem.

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
main
main.py
  plugins
    plugin1
      a.py
      b.py
```

b.py has its first line

`import a`

What I want is for main.py to be able to dynamically load plugins from the plugins directory

Accordingly I have set it up as such

```
import importlib

plugin = "plugin1" #the hope is that this will be defined dynamically eventually

plugin_name = ".b"
plugin_module = importlib.import_module(plugin_name, "Plugins." + plugin1)
```

I was hoping that by adding a relative reference in the plugin_module importlib command that "b" would successfully find "a" when run but I get the error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'.

I am assuming that while it attempts to run b, it is unable to find a - but would be great if there was a way around this that used importlib (since being able to dynamically define which I am using is essential for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to importlib; if you imported the module explicitly, like `from plugins.plugin1 import b`, you would see the same problem. It is because `a` is not a module, the actual module name is `plugins.plugin1.a`.

You have to use relative imports in the plugin. Change `import a` to `from . import a`